# Выравнивание иконки относительно текста

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  transition: .3s;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

i.fa {
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

i.fa-angle-down {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="header_topline">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i>Услуги<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Новости</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Задача стоит поместить "эту галочку" по центру относительно текста. Спасибо за ответ!

[image: Иконка]

Comment: Добавьте свой код в вопрос.

Comment: Без примера непонятно, с чем у вас возникли затруднения

Comment: Если уж не докрепили Font Awesome в пример, укажите хотя бы используемую вами версию

Comment: @andreymal 4.7.

Comment: Добавьте `vertical-align: middle` для иконки

Comment: @fanfer Помогло. Спасибо.